# Benchmarking connection time interval in Android across different phones

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hello Android and Embedded devs community, I have a question related to BLE connection intervals. I am developing an efficient hardware prototype which relies on tight data transfer rate and I would like to be able to perform an adequate benchmark of the BLE connection parameters from the Android phone (since there are so many of them with such different hardware!).

Just to recall some easy concepts, [taken from here](http://www.novelbits.io/ble-connection-intervals/).

> A BLE connection interval is the time between two data transfer events
>   (BLE connection events) between the central and the peripheral device.
>   The theoretical value ranges from 7.5 ms to 4 secs (with increments of
>   1.25 ms).
>
> The connection is established with the interval parameter value set by the master (central) device. However, the peripheral may
>   suggest/request different values. The master still has the final say
>   in the values and may end up choosing values different than but closer
>   to the requested values.

The master in my system is the phone, hence the need for performing an adequate benchmark to test which phones will be able to work for the final user.

Is there a way on Android to perform this analysis and obtain the BLE connection parameters directly on the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to solve this issue by timing the following callback on my Android app:

```
@Override public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,BluetoothGattCharacteristic 
{
  /* Timing code measuring msecs between calls. */ 
}
```

This has worked perfectly to perform the benchmark I was looking for.